# Scripting error: ';' expected. Unity error

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have this error on this script while following a tutorial

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject prefab;

    // Instantiate the Prefab somewhere between -10.0 and 10.0 on the x-z plane
    void Start()
    {
        Vector3 position = new Vector3(Random.Range(-10.0f, 10.0f), 0, Random.Range(-10.0f, 10.0f))
        Instantiate(prefab, position, Quaternion.identity)
    }
}
```

Comment: This is `c#` ... every statement ends with a `;` ... maybe you should get into some basic `c#` first before jumping into Unity development?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember to put ";" at the end of lines like this

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour
{
public GameObject prefab;

// Instantiate the Prefab somewhere between -10.0 and 10.0 on the x-z plane
void Start()
{
    Vector3 position = new Vector3(Random.Range(-10.0f, 10.0f), 0, Random.Range(-10.0f, 10.0f));
    Instantiate(prefab, position, Quaternion.identity);
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Statements need to be terminated with `;`

[Statements (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/statements)

> **A statement can consist of a single line of code that ends in a
>   semicolon**, or a series of single-line statements in a block

```
Vector3 position = new Vector3(...); <== note the semicolon
Instantiate(...); <== note the semicolon
```

Which is what the error is telling you

Answer (score 0):

this is how your script should look like.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour
{
public GameObject prefab;

// Instantiate the Prefab somewhere between -10.0 and 10.0 on the x-z plane
void Start()
{
    Vector3 position = new Vector3(Random.Range(-10.0f, 10.0f), 0, Random.Range(-10.0f, 10.0f));
    Instantiate(prefab, position, Quaternion.identity);
}
}
```